# Specifying a custom logging Linux filepath in Python 2

Tags: python, linux, logging

I'm trying to understand how logfiles work with the [Python 2 `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).

I know that I can save the log output to a text file using something like:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

It's not clear to me from the documentation on:

1. Whether or not *absolute* `filename` paths are valid
2. The proper syntax for specifying *relative* paths (assuming that `../example.log` is valid).

If I execute this script from `/home/bob`, how do I specify that I want the logfile saved to the `/tmp` directory instead - using both absolute and relative paths?

Is `logging.basicConfig(filename='../../tmp/example.log')` valid?

Similarly, is `logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/example.log')` valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When stating just the filename, it would be written to the **current directory**.
Using Python IDLE you can check that as follows

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(filename='relative.log')
>>> logging.info('test')

C:\Python27\relative.log
```

My working dir is Python27, and I have a file there named relative.log with my logged message.

When you change the file location to `../relative.log`, I get a new file at the parent directory of Python27. So **relative path** does work for logging:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(filename='../relative.log')
>>> logging.info('test123')

C:\relative.log
```

And `logging` module also supports **absolute path**:

```
>>> logging.basicConfig(filename=r'c:\abs_path.log')
>>> logging.info('test')

C:\abs_path.log
```

It is always better to use absolute path, as **explicit is better than implicit**.

Comment: Thanks - this is admittedly sort of a dumb question. I've verified that absolute paths will also work with Linux environments.

Comment: It will, just note if you are running it on Windows platform, you need to add `r` for raw before writing the path, otherwise it will throw an error unless you escape every slash in your path

Answer (score 1):

They are both valid. But relative paths (with ..) will select different files depending on the directory you are in when you run it.

So when you run `logger.py` in `/home/user/projects/python` and the filename is `../log.txt` the file will be saved in `/home/user/projects`. On the other hand when you run the script in `/home/user` then `log.txt` will be saved in `/home/`.

Absolute paths always work and are more reliable. If you want a file in the current directory I recommend this approach:

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(basedir, 'file.txt')
```